# Turn a string into function in JS

Tags: javascript, string, function, transform

My problem is simple and I couldn't find the proper answer in this forum. My bad...

I want to do that :

```
    const dataReceived = foo;
    foo(state);
```

How can I do that?
I read it is better to avoid eval, and I couldn't get success with new Function.
Thanks for your help!

EDIT
Thanks for your answers.
I work with React.
In my reducer, I have a create_item case.
I can reach action.category, that can be the word 'currency' or 'country'.

What I want to do is to launch either the method createCurrency or createCountry according what is inside action.category.
That's why I tried to join 'create' and 'action.category' to create a dynamic function name.
But it seems to be a poor idea...

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. There's nothing in your question that would require `eval` or `new Function`.

Comment: Should your existing code + some example data. It isn't clear what you're trying to do at all. // What actual problem are you trying to solve? Where does the string come from?

Comment: @Liam That's one possible interpretation of the question, but yes it's kind of unclear.

Comment: No, dont' do that. Functions are not data, and they should not be treated like data.

Comment: @Teemu, there's no reason to not assign a function to a property, it's done all the time. That's the basis why functions are first class objects in JS

Comment: What is the value of `foo`? What role does `dataReceived` play? What is the value of `state`? You are just showing how the value of one variable is assigned to another variable and how one variable is called as a function. If `foo` holds a function value that your code works as is. Please provide more information, it's unclear what the problem is.

Comment: @Liam Ehh ... What? How is that related to functions as data? Notice, that in the title OP says they want to make a function out of a string, the example doesn't make much sense in that context, but what OP says they have tried.

Comment: With respect to your update, @rounin's answer would be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to create an `object` which contains an `entry` where:

- the `key` is a `string`
- the `value` is a `function`.

**Example:**

```
const myObject = {

  myFunction: () => { [... DO SOMETHING...] }

}
```

Subsequently you will be able to invoke the function, using:

```
myObject.myFunction();
```

---

The above becomes more powerful when you use brackets notation.

**Example:**

```
const myString = 'myFunction';

myObject[myString]();
```